# How to get a Gradle (test) task to use code from a different test folder in the same project (Java)

Tags: java, testing, gradle, scope, dependencies

I'm completely new to Gradle and I'm having some test dependency/scope issues with my task.

Currently my project is set up something like

```
/root
build.gradle
    /test
        /testA
        /testB
```

I have a class in testA package that imports a class in testB package. When I run the task or do a gradle build, it cannot find symbol for that class, which I assume is because the two packages are out of scope of each other. How can I configure my testA task for testA to be able to find stuff (or at least that particular class) in testB? (Both testA and testB tasks are in the same build.gradle file)

Comment: Are testA and testB different projects? Or different packages in the same project?

Comment: Different packages in the same project. TestB is also an integration test built using groovy and TestA is java if that matters.

Comment: Could you reorganize your project to use the [standard directory layout](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N15104), and put the classes from testA and testB under `src/test/java`?